# Why does the nested cursor keep pulling the same result infinitely

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a procedure that has a nested cursor to return the rooms of the hotel, with a nested cursor inside that cursor to return the cost for that room over the different periods of time. However, when I run my procedure, I get the hotel id and name (as I should), the room name and description (as I should), but then the first cost value gets infinitely printed out.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_GetRackRates
@HotelID smallint
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @HotelName      varchar(30)
    DECLARE @RoomID         smallint
    DECLARE @RoomNumber     smallint
    DECLARE @RTDescription  varchar(200)
    DECLARE @RackRate       smallmoney
    DECLARE @RackRateBegin  date
    DECLARE @RackRateEnd    date

    SELECT @HotelName = HotelName
    FROM Hotel
    WHERE HotelID = @HotelID

    PRINT 'Hotel ID: ' + CAST(@HotelID AS varchar(max)) + ' - ' + CAST(@HotelName as 
    varchar(max))

    PRINT ' '

    SELECT @RoomID = RoomID, @RoomNumber = RoomNumber, @RTDescription = RTDescription
    FROM (Room
    INNER JOIN RoomType ON Room.RoomTypeID = RoomType.RoomTypeID)
    WHERE Room.HotelID = @HotelID


    SELECT @RackRate = RackRate, @RackRateBegin = RackRateBegin, @RackRateEnd = 
           RackRateEnd
    FROM (RackRate
    INNER JOIN Room ON RackRate.HotelID = Room.HotelID)
    WHERE RackRate.HotelID = @HotelID AND RoomNumber = @RoomNumber


    DECLARE cr_GetRoom CURSOR
    FOR 
    SELECT RoomID, RoomNumber, RTDescription
    FROM (Room
    INNER JOIN RoomType ON Room.RoomTypeID = RoomType.RoomTypeID)
    WHERE Room.HotelID = @HotelID

    DECLARE cr_GetRackRates CURSOR
    FOR
    SELECT RackRate, RackRateBegin, RackRateEnd
    FROM (RackRate
    INNER JOIN Room ON RackRate.HotelID = Room.HotelID)
    WHERE RackRate.HotelID = @HotelID AND RoomNumber = @RoomNumber

    OPEN cr_GetRoom

    FETCH NEXT FROM cr_GetRoom
    INTO @RoomID, @RoomNumber, @RTDescription

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Room ' + CAST(@RoomNumber AS varchar(max)) + ': ' + CAST(@RTDescription 
               as varchar(max))

        OPEN cr_GetRackRates
        FETCH NEXT FROM cr_GetRackRates
        INTO @RackRate, @RackRateBegin, @RackRateEnd

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'Rate: $' + CAST(@RackRate as varchar(max)) + ' valid ' + 
                   cast(@RackRateBegin AS varchar(max)) + ' to ' + CAST(@RackRateEnd AS 
                   varchar(max))
        END
        CLOSE cr_GetRackRates

        PRINT ' '
    END

    CLOSE cr_GetRoom
    DEALLOCATE cr_GetRackRates
    DEALLOCATE cr_GetRoom
END
```

A Sample output looks as follows:

```
HotelID: 2100 - Sunridge B&B

Room 101: Single
Rate: $125.00 valid 2023-03-16 to 2023-11-14
Rate: $125.00 valid 2023-03-16 to 2023-11-14
Rate: $125.00 valid 2023-03-16 to 2023-11-14
Rate: $125.00 valid 2023-03-16 to 2023-11-14
Rate: $125.00 valid 2023-03-16 to 2023-11-14
Rate: $125.00 valid 2023-03-16 to 2023-11-14
Rate: $125.00 valid 2023-03-16 to 2023-11-14
```

Where the Rate: $125.00 continues infinitely, even though there is only one of those values in the database.

Why does the nested cursor keep repeating the same value? I've tried using SELECT DISTINCT but it kept giving the same results.

Comment: I would rather rewrite your query using set-based and not spend time on debugging the cursor query. Cursor query are usually does not perform very well.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: I will definitely use this for next time. I posted an answer to my question because I figured out I was just being dumb.

Comment: Fyi there is absolutely no need to use a cursor, a set-based approach will be far more performant.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what my issue was.

In the blocks

```
FETCH NEXT FROM cr_GetRoom
    INTO @RoomID, @RoomNumber, @RTDescription

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Room ' + CAST(@RoomNumber AS varchar(max)) + ': ' + CAST(@RTDescription 
               as varchar(max))

        OPEN cr_GetRackRates
        FETCH NEXT FROM cr_GetRackRates
        INTO @RackRate, @RackRateBegin, @RackRateEnd

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'Rate: $' + CAST(@RackRate as varchar(max)) + ' valid ' + 
                   cast(@RackRateBegin AS varchar(max)) + ' to ' + CAST(@RackRateEnd AS 
                   varchar(max))
        END
        CLOSE cr_GetRackRates

        PRINT ' '
    END
```

I was not fetching the next item, so it was just sitting at the same item constantly returning it.

It should be:

```
FETCH NEXT FROM cr_GetRoom
    INTO @RoomID, @RoomNumber, @RTDescription

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Room ' + CAST(@RoomNumber AS varchar(max)) + ': ' + CAST(@RTDescription 
               as varchar(max))

        OPEN cr_GetRackRates
        FETCH NEXT FROM cr_GetRackRates
        INTO @RackRate, @RackRateBegin, @RackRateEnd

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'Rate: $' + CAST(@RackRate as varchar(max)) + ' valid ' + 
                   cast(@RackRateBegin AS varchar(max)) + ' to ' + CAST(@RackRateEnd AS 
                   varchar(max))
            FETCH NEXT FROM cr_GetRackRates
            INTO @RackRate, @RackRateBegin, @RackRateEnd
        END
        CLOSE cr_GetRackRates

        PRINT ' '
        FETCH NEXT FROM cr_GetRoom
        INTO @RoomID, @RoomNumber, @RTDescription
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to mix cursors with regular variable fetching and not doing actual loops, and declaring the cursors in wrong position so i'm gonna assume your fixed code doesn't work, so please forgive me if my assumption is not correct.

The improved(?) version:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetRackRates
@HotelID smallint
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @HotelName      varchar(30)
    DECLARE @RoomID         smallint
    DECLARE @RoomNumber     smallint
    DECLARE @RTDescription  varchar(200)
    DECLARE @RackRate       smallmoney
    DECLARE @RackRateBegin  date
    DECLARE @RackRateEnd    date
    
    SELECT @HotelName = HotelName
    FROM Hotel
    WHERE HotelID = @HotelID
    
    PRINT 'Hotel ID: ' + CAST(@HotelID AS varchar(max)) + ' - ' + CAST(@HotelName as 
    varchar(max))
    
    PRINT ' '

    DECLARE cr_GetRoom CURSOR READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY LOCAL STATIC FOR 
        SELECT  RoomID, RoomNumber, RTDescription
        FROM    Room
        INNER JOIN RoomType ON Room.RoomTypeID = RoomType.RoomTypeID
        WHERE   Room.HotelID = @HotelID

    OPEN cr_GetRoom
        
    WHILE 1 = 1
    BEGIN
        FETCH NEXT FROM cr_GetRoom
        INTO @RoomID, @RoomNumber, @RTDescription
        
        IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0
            BREAK
            
        DECLARE cr_GetRackRates CURSOR READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY LOCAL STATIC FOR
            SELECT  RackRate, RackRateBegin, RackRateEnd
            FROM    RackRate
            INNER JOIN Room ON RackRate.HotelID = Room.HotelID
            WHERE   RackRate.HotelID = @HotelID AND RoomNumber = @RoomNumber
        
        OPEN cr_GetRackRates
        
        WHILE 1 = 1
        BEGIN
            FETCH NEXT FROM cr_GetRackRates
            INTO @RackRate, @RackRateBegin, @RackRateEnd

            IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0
                BREAK
                
            PRINT 'Room ' + CAST(@RoomNumber AS varchar(max)) + ': ' + CAST(@RTDescription as varchar(max))
            PRINT 'Rate: $' + CAST(@RackRate as varchar(max)) + ' valid ' + 
                   cast(@RackRateBegin AS varchar(max)) + ' to ' + CAST(@RackRateEnd AS 
                   varchar(max))
        END
        PRINT ' '
        CLOSE cr_GetRackRates
        DEALLOCATE cr_GetRackRates
    END
    CLOSE cr_GetRoom
    DEALLOCATE cr_GetRoom
    
END
```

A couple of points:

1. Unless you want to update data, you should declare your cursors as local static, which avoids pollution the namespace of cursors, and also improve your performance.
2. You have to declare the inner cursor "inside" the loop after your fetch the room number, otherwise it just becomes static bound to the original room variable.
3. I prefer to use WHERE 1 = 1 loops and check for fetch_status after the fetching of variables. This is because a lot of times one forgets to fetch the variables again in the end of the loop which messes things up.

Comment: My solution did fix the problem, although this one is cleaner. I did make a few changes to it to get the results I wanted.